# Build a histogram of road speed based on road length by grouping road segments

Tags: oracle, group-by, query, statistics

A data set look like this:

[image]

The table doesn't have sum(segLength yet), but can be computed by summing up `sum(segLength) from road_table group by roadID`
A `roadID` (e.i. Lake Street) belongs to a `roadType` (e.i. St) and consists of segments (e.i. `segID` is 2005 for a given road block).

I want to plot average speeds of roads grouped by road lengths further grouped by road types like shown in example output below.

[image]

How to add columns for each `roadType`, within each `roadType` group roads into bins, within each bin compute average value of `maxSpeed`?

I'm using PL/SQL. I can translate a query from MySQL or PostgreSQL if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following ideas will give you a starting point for developing your queries.  We need some test data first.  The last SEGID in your question is: 4007.  In the example, we are using a table with 4500 random SEGLENGTHs, and IDs, maxspeeds etc similar to the ones you have described (in your sample table).

TEST table and data (Oracle 12c)

```
create table test ( 
  segid number generated always as identity primary key 
, roadid number
, roadtype varchar2( 64 )
, seglength number ( 10, 1 )
, maxspeed number
, check ( maxspeed between 0 and 100 )
); 

insert into test( roadid, roadtype, seglength, maxspeed )
select 
  roadid
, case
    when roadid < 200 then 'Ave'
    when roadid between 200 and 400 then 'Hwy'
    when roadid between 401 and 700 then 'St'
    when roadid between 701 and 900 then 'Rd'
  end roadtype
, round( dbms_random.value() * 10, 2 ) 
, case
    when roadid < 200 then ( mod( roadid, 4 ) + 1 ) * 10 
    when roadid between 200 and 400 then ( mod( roadid, 7 ) + 1 ) * 10 
    when roadid between 401 and 700 then ( mod( roadid, 3 ) + 1 ) * 10  
    when roadid between 701 and 900 then ( mod( roadid, 6 ) + 1 ) * 10  
  end maxspeed
from 
  ( select level roadid from dual connect by level <= 900 )
, ( select level segcount from dual connect by level <= 5 ) 
;
```

TEST table: first 5 rows, last 5 rows

```
SQL> select * from test order by segid fetch first 5 rows only;
SEGID  ROADID  ROADTYPE  SEGLENGTH  MAXSPEED  
1      1       Ave       1.6        20        
2      1       Ave       7.5        20        
3      1       Ave       3.8        20        
4      1       Ave       9.2        20        
5      1       Ave       2.8        20        

SQL> select * from test order by segid offset 4495 rows fetch next 5 rows only;
SEGID  ROADID  ROADTYPE  SEGLENGTH  MAXSPEED  
4496   900     Rd        4.2        10        
4497   900     Rd        4.2        10        
4498   900     Rd        0.7        10        
4499   900     Rd        7.1        10        
4500   900     Rd        2          10
```

For dividing the SEGLENGTH into "buckets", you could use WIDTH_BUCKET() (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions250.htm#SQLRF06163)), and use GROUP BY to find the average speed for each "bucket".

```
  select 
    roadtype, avg( maxspeed ), max( seglength ), wb
  from 
  (
      select roadtype, maxspeed, seglength
      , width_bucket( 
          seglength
        , ( select min( seglength ) from test )
        , ( select max( seglength ) from test ) + 1  -- upper bucket count: exclusive!
        , 5 
       ) wb    
      from test 
    )
  group by wb, roadtype 

-- result
ROADTYPE  AVG(MAXSPEED)                              MAX(SEGLENGTH)  WB  
Hwy       39.24170616113744075829383886255924170616  8.7             4   
Hwy       40.70866141732283464566929133858267716535  10              5   
St        18.91304347826086956521739130434782608696  8.7             4   
St        19.81132075471698113207547169811320754717  10              5   
Rd        34.70588235294117647058823529411764705882  6.5             3   
Ave       24.49275362318840579710144927536231884058  10              5   
Hwy       41.76744186046511627906976744186046511628  6.5             3   
Ave       25.52995391705069124423963133640552995392  2.1             1   
Ave       24.0796019900497512437810945273631840796   8.7             4   
Ave       25.27272727272727272727272727272727272727  4.3             2   
St        20.50632911392405063291139240506329113924  2.1             1   
Rd        34.51754385964912280701754385964912280702  8.7             4   
Rd        35.11811023622047244094488188976377952756  10              5   
Hwy       38.68312757201646090534979423868312757202  4.3             2   
Rd        35.26315789473684210526315789473684210526  2.1             1   
Rd        35.52995391705069124423963133640552995392  4.3             2   
Ave       25.70776255707762557077625570776255707763  6.5             3   
Hwy       40.28708133971291866028708133971291866029  2.1             1   
St        21.03658536585365853658536585365853658537  4.3             2   
St        19.65838509316770186335403726708074534161  6.5             3
```

Add a PIVOT() to this query, in order to convert the ROADTYPES into columns, and use ROUND() or TRUNC() for obtaining the final values.

```
select msl, ave, hwy, st, rd
from (
  select 
    roadtype, trunc( avg( maxspeed ) ) ams, max( seglength ) msl, wb
  from 
  (
    select roadtype, maxspeed, seglength
    , width_bucket( 
        seglength
      , ( select min( seglength ) from test )
      , ( select max( seglength ) from test ) + 1  -- upper bucket count: exclusive!
      , 5 
     ) wb    
    from test 
  )
  group by wb, roadtype 
) pivot  (
    avg( ams ) for roadtype in (  -- pivot() requires an aggregate function
      'Ave' as ave
    , 'Hwy' as hwy
    , 'St'  as st
    , 'Rd'  as rd
   )
) P
order by wb
;

-- result    
       MSL        AVE        HWY         ST         RD
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       2.1         25         40         20         35
       4.3         25         38         21         35
       6.5         25         41         19         34
       8.7         24         39         18         34
        10         24         40         19         35
```

For getting the standard deviation values, just use STDDEV() instead of AVG().